# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 in win 7 core 2 duo machine using Vmware

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I have a Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU with 2GB RAM,32-bit windows 7 loaded.

I need to run Ubuntu in Vmware, but even the Desktop of ubuntu is not loading properly.

What are the possible solutions ?

How much more RAM is required ?

Comment: What you mean by "not loading properly"? Have you enabled 3D and installed "guest additions" (this is the name in Virtualbox, may be different in VMWare). How much ram is reserved to your virtual machine?